# Random Number between 1 and 0 in matrix ocaml

Tags: arrays, matrix, random, ocaml

I am trying to build a matrix in OCaml consisting only of 1 and 0. My current code is

```
let myArray = Array.make_matrix num num2 (Random.int 2) in 
  print myArray
```

However this fills the entire array up with only 0 or only 1, and not a combination, is there a way for me to do what i want?

Comment: You could `map` the values in the array.

Comment: would you recommend me using Array.map in a nested for loop in order to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `Array.make_matrix` fills the matrix with a single value that you supply.

You can write this:

```
let myArray =
    Array.init num
        (fun _ -> Array.init num2 (fun _ -> Random.int 2))
```

Here's how it looks:

```
# let num = 2;;
val num : int = 2
# let num2 = 3;;
val num2 : int = 3
# let myArray =
    Array.init num
        (fun _ -> Array.init num2 (fun _ -> Random.int 2));;  
val myArray : int array array = [|[|0; 1; 0|]; [|1; 1; 0|]|]
#
```

**Update**

If you want different numbers each time, you need to initialize the random number generator with a different seed each time. An easy way to do this is:

```
Random.self_init ()
```

You can call this once at program startup, and you'll get different random numbers in each run of the program.

Comment: I tested out, but the numbers seem to be the same every time, is that supposed to happen? I was wondering if there was a way for it to vary each time I run it

Comment: I'm trying to do the game of life in OCaml, and working thorugh matrices rather than graphics which is why I'm asking

Comment: You need to initialize the random number generator if you want different numbers each time.